# uiwebview wrap problem with long words

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i have a webview in my application and it works fine. it fits horizontolly (not scrolls) and scrolls vertically. but any word which is longer than 320 pixel makes it scrolls horizantally and makes the font larger. i don't would like horizontal scroll. i would like it to be continued in new line. how can i do?

thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem you have is actually not related to the `UIWebView` in itself. What the web view does is just display any html you provide. This means that you have to format the html to do as you want. One way to accomplish that is to use a `div` as follows.

```
<div style="width: 320px; word-wrap: break-word">
text with looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongword goes here
</div>
```

*Caveat: I don't know very much about html and css so there might be better ways of accomplishing this.*

Comment: I tried finding a solution to this problem for about 4 hours today. Kept thinking it was related to the UIWebView until I came here. Thank you for the answer, it saved me a lot more frustration.